# I need help decomposing a relation to BCNF

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a table that has the following functional dependencies;

- PropertyID → Address, Price
- AgentName → AgentPhone
- Price → SalesTax
- CustomerName → CustomerPhone
- AgentName, Price → Commission

I have decomposed it to the following.

1. Property (**PropertyID**, Address, Price)
2. Agent (**AgentName**, AgentPhone)
3. Customer (**CustomerName**, CustomerPhone)
4. Price (**Price***, **AgentName***, PropertyID *, SalesTax, Commision)

It still seems a bit clunky to me, but I can't see how I could decompose it further.

Comment: What does bold font in your decomposition mean?

Comment: Primary key. I couldn't workout how to underline.

Answer (score 1):

Items 1, 2, and 3 in your decomposition are right. You seem to have lost the FD "Price->SalesTax".  And item 4 is not in 2NF, because of the partial-key dependency "Price->SalesTax".

- {**PropertyID**, Address, Price}
- {**AgentName**, AgentPhone}
- {**CustomerName**, CustomerPhone}
- {**Price**, SalesTax}
- {**AgentName, Price**, Commission}

All of these are in at least 5NF.  The correct decomposition is identical to the functional dependencies you started with. That doesn't happen very often.